# Por qué tengo que repetir la linea de código para que funcione

Tags: php, mysqli, php7

Para obtener los datos no me funciona haciendo el *assoc* a la primera variable *login_token_select* si no que tengo que repetir esa línea, es decir volver a hacer la consulta para que el *assoc* funcione, no hay manera de hacerlo sin tener que repetir el código?

```
$login_token_select = mysqli_query($base,"SELECT * FROM $users WHERE token = '$login_token'");
    
    if (mysqli_fetch_row($login_token_select) > 0 && mysqli_fetch_row($login_token_select) < 1) {
        
        // TENGO QUE REPETIRLA AQUÍ PARA QUE OBTENGA LOS DATOS
        //$login_token_select = mysqli_query($base,"SELECT * FROM $users WHERE token = '$login_token'");
    
        while ($login_token_get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login_token_select)) {
            
            echo "Hola ".$login_token_get['name']."<br>Naciste el ".$login_token_get['birthday'];
            
        }
        
    } else{}
```

Comment: no debería ser ... pero tu script tambien esta mal planteado ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `mysqli_query()` devuelve un recurso de acceso a base de datos con un apuntador para obtener los resultados y avanza cada vez que usas `mysqli_fetch_*()`; de hecho, me extraña que te funcione, porque debería dar un error al llegar al final del conjunto de resultados, porque las funciones `mysqli_fetch_*()` devuelven un arreglo o falso si no se obtuvieron registros en la consulta o el apuntador llegó al final; y:

```
// Comparas (arreglo o falso) > 0 y avanzas el apuntador
mysqli_fetch_row($login_token_select) > 0
// Comparas (arreglo o falso) < 1 y avanzas nuevamente el apuntador
mysqli_fetch_row($login_token_select) < 1
```

Luego, en el ciclo debes ejecutar nuevamente la consulta porque el apuntador ya llegó al final. Si el token es único, simplemente debes analizar el resultado de `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, en caso de ser falso, no se obtuvieron coincidencias:

```
//$login_token_select = mysqli_query($base,"SELECT * FROM $users WHERE token = '$login_token'");
$login_token_get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login_token_select);
if($login_token_get !== false) {
    echo "Hola ".$login_token_get['name']."<br>Naciste el ".$login_token_get['birthday'];
} else {
    // Error, no se encontró el usuario
}
```

Si puede haber tokens repetidos, entonces tienes un problema con el diseño de tu proyecto.

Comment: no esta usando `mysql_query` esta usando `mysqli_query`

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent, error de tecleo, ya lo corregí. ¡Gracias!

Comment: para eso estamos XD

Answer (score 2):

tu script tambien esta mal planteado, yo utilizaría el método `num_rows` para validar si hay registros:

```php
$login_token_select = mysqli_query($base,"SELECT * FROM $users WHERE token = '$login_token'");
if ($login_token_select->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($login_token_get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login_token_select)) {
        echo "Hola ".$login_token_get['name']."<br>Naciste el ".$login_token_get['birthday']
    }
}
```

no debes usar `mysqli_fetch_assoc` para validar; ya que este método retorna el avance de las filas que haya retornado tu consulta cada vez que lo ejecutas.

[Documentacion relacionada a num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)